# How to load Slim flash vars in Twig

Tags: twig, slim

I'm using Slim Framework and Twig template engine, I can not understand how to use "flash vars" in the view.
I tried

```
{{flash.prev}}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For flash messages to work you need to use sessions, either the default PHP session handler or SessionCookie which comes with Slim, if you do not use SessionCookie you need to start the PHP session manually with session_start();

There are a few Flash function, personally I use flash() and flashNow() mostly. flash() gives you the variable in the next response (after a redirect for example) whereas flashNow() gives you the variable in the current response.

```
session_start(); //I manually start the session here.

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    $app->flash('test', 'This is the message');
    $app->redirect($app->urlFor('test'));
});

$app->get('/test', function() use ($app) {
    var_dump($_SESSION['slim.flash']);
    $app->render('test.twig');
})->name('test');
```

And in the templates/test.twig file

```
<h1>{{flash.test}}</h1>
```

In the above example you will see that the var_dump will give an array with the 'test' key and the 'This is the message' value. In Twig I would be able to fetch this with

```
{{flash.test}}
```

Documentation on all of the above: http://docs.slimframework.com/#Flash-Messaging-Overview

Comment: Are you sure that `flash` is directly accessible in the view?

Comment: Yes. I have changed my example to include a template

Comment: session_start() was my issue! Thank you!